# ".format(name, e)) ... google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Failed to parse textPayload field: expected string or bytes-like object." GCF logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging

I changed the logging in a Google Cloud Function from the built-in Python module `logging` to `google.cloud.logging` and I cannot seem to export exceptions and error messages since they have the wrong type - expected string or bytes-like object.

A shortcut of the error:

> _ConvertFieldValuePair raise ParseError('Failed to parse {0} field: {1}.'.format(name, e)) google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Failed
> to parse textPayload field: expected string or bytes-like object.

The full error from the Google Cloud Logs:

> ````
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 2073, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1518, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1516, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1502, in dispatch_request return
> self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py",
> line 99, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object())
> File "/workspace/main.py", line 518, in get_sql_and_save_as_csv_in_gcs
> store_duplicated_alids(conn_for_delete_insert, logger) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dryable/__init__.py",
> line 34, in _decorated return function( * args, ** kwargs ) File
> "/workspace/main.py", line 368, in store_duplicated_alids
> logger.log_text(e) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/logger.py",
> line 189, in log_text self._do_log(client, TextEntry, text, **kw) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/logger.py",
> line 158, in _do_log client.logging_api.write_entries([api_repr]) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py",
> line 151, in write_entries log_entry_pbs =
> [_log_entry_mapping_to_pb(entry) for entry in entries] File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py",
> line 151, in <listcomp> log_entry_pbs =
> [_log_entry_mapping_to_pb(entry) for entry in entries] File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py",
> line 542, in _log_entry_mapping_to_pb ParseDict(mapping, entry_pb)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py",
> line 445, in ParseDict parser.ConvertMessage(js_dict, message) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py",
> line 476, in ConvertMessage self._ConvertFieldValuePair(value,
> message) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py",
> line 594, in _ConvertFieldValuePair raise ParseError('Failed to parse
> {0} field: {1}.'.format(name, e))
> google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Failed to parse textPayload
> field: expected string or bytes-like object.  ```
> ````

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Workaround

You can cast all of your exceptions (and errors) to string.

Example

```py
    except Exception as e:
        logger.log_text(str(e))
        raise
```

This is still a strange workaround, I would have expected the module to have a better way for this. I tried [StackDriver Logging python exception in protobuf json_format.py](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6217)
and it did not work. Any other ideas welcome.